# How can I execute an R script from imageJ/Fiji?

Tags: r, imagej, fiji

I have written an R script (that perfectly works on R) that I would like to run in Fiji. I see that Fiji can understand the R language, but mine doesn't seem to do anything when I hit "run".

Is there a line code to specify at the beginning of the script in Fiji, or is there a Java package to download ? If Fiji indicates that the script can be in R it's that it must be working, but I haven't find a way yet.

Comment: You can try to use the script editor or interpreter in Fiji/ImageJ2.
https://imagej.net/Scripting